# measure bandwidth for docker pull using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I have a python script that pulls images using the docker SDK for python, and after each image is pulled I want to print out the bytes in / bytes out.

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this, it seems that the docker library doesn't support this so currently I am thinking of using `subprocess` and `ifconfig` and parsing the data that way... except it seems very overkill for what should be a simple task.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `ifconfig` will not help you, because if there's any other process running in the background and using the same interface you will get statistics for both the docker pull and the other process.
What is the goal of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Hagai I want some numbers so i can compare between different images and also rsync

Comment: I'd recommend to use the methods described in this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth
To check the bandwidth of your docker process